# Why does text keyboard show on Android's TimePicker's onScroll?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, timepicker

When using a `TimePicker` set to `spinner` mode, if I click on a number (minutes or hours), the number keyboard shows up.

[image]

But whenever I scroll any of the spinners, the keyboard changes to the text `inputType`.

[image]

How can I avoid this?

I've tried calling `timePicker.setAddStatesFromChildren(true)` and setting an `OnTimeChangedListener`, but that won't work, for if I scroll just enough for the spinner to move but not for the time to change, the listener is not triggered but the keyboard changes to text `inputType` anyway.

Also, `timePicker.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)` is not what I'm looking for, for I still want the keyboard to show up, but only that it won't change its `inputType` to `text`.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I couldn't find which view was making the keyboard appear. I tried removing the next focus from every view inside the TimePicker, but nothing. Then, I thought the problem was that, since I was using a 24-hour format spinner, the view to blame was the hidden AM/PM `CustomTextView` inside the `TimePicker`. I made it non-focusable, but still the same issue. So I concluded that the problem was somewhere in the implementation of the TimePicker itself, who manages some event and displays the keyboard.

So I decided to iterate over the `NumberPicker`s inside `TimePicker` —which are three— and set an `OnScrollListener` on them that hides the keyboard. But still, I get to see the text keyboard appearing before being dismissed. But that's the best I've managed to do.

```
public static <T extends View> List<T> getViewsByClassNameFromView(ViewGroup viewGroup, Class<T> clazz) {

    final List<T> matches = new LinkedList<>();

    final int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (clazz.isInstance(child)) {
            matches.add((T) child);
        } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            matches.addAll(getViewsByClassNameFromView((ViewGroup) child, clazz));
        }
    }

    return matches;
}

public void hideSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm =
            (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    view.clearFocus();
}

private void fixTimePicker() {
    final List<NumberPicker> numberPickers = ViewUtil.getViewsByClassNameFromView(timePicker, NumberPicker.class);
    for (final NumberPicker numberPicker: numberPickers) {
        numberPicker.setOnScrollListener(new NumberPicker.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChange(NumberPicker view, int scrollState) {
                hideSoftKeyboard(view);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" use this attribute in DatePicker Xml and it will resolve your issue.

Comment: I edited the answer just a moment ago. We don't want to block the keyboard. We only want it not to be text type.